# Magento2 create custom dynamic routes

Tags: magento2, url

Magento2 how can I create custom dynamically routes/URL ?

I need URLs as below

```
For e.g. https://example/find-a-store/nsw/tuggerah/
```

Here in URL, nsw & tuggerah will dynamic generate

I used below code but not able to get what I want

```
public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
   { //echo "string";die();
       $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
       if(strpos($identifier, 'customrouter') !== false) {
       $request->setModuleName('findastore')-> //module name
       setControllerName('nsw')-> //controller name
       setActionName('tug')-> //action name
       setParam('param', 3); //custom parameters
       } else {
           return false;
       }
       return $this->actionFactory->create(
           'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
           ['request' => $request]
       );
   }
```

Comment: are you able to get into this method? I mean `echo string`  is displaying?

Comment: yes i am able to

Comment: I've answered below in detail if you want to check more than one URLs but if you just want to redirect based on only one occurrence of some keyword in your URL then in `strpos($identifier, /*write a keyword from your URL here i-e find-a-store*/)`then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
```

get url parts like below, you can check 4 with greater values according to your URL:

```
$url_parts = explode("/", $identifier, 4);
```

then check if `$url_parts` contains the url parts you want to work on:

```
if (($url_parts[0]) == 'example') && ($url_parts[1] == 'find-a-store' /*and so on*/)) {
            $request->setModuleName('findastore');
            $request->setControllerName('nsw');
            $request->setActionName('tug');
            $request->setParams([
                'id' => $id
            ]);
            return $this->actionFactory->create(Forward::class, ['request' => $request]);
        }
```

Hope it works.

Comment: getting error 'The action name provided is invalid. Verify the action name and try again.'

Comment: I think the code is working, problem is perhaps with controller name or namespace/path. You can verify that.